# Yii2 startup kit rbac role permission

Tags: yii2, user-roles, user-management, rbac

Im using this startup application for my app trntv/yii2-starter-kit,

Is there any option to add permissions and assign permissions to role using front end? how can i integrate the front end for rbac? please help me to do the frontend for roles and permissions

Comment: which "this startup application" ? a link? some other info? please provide more information

Comment: https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit - i want to create front end for permissions and role